# Git Merge message issue (Vim?)

Tags: git, vim

I'm starting to learn git, and am on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I make the command `git merge master`, it brings me to a (I think) Vim window to enter the merge message.  The problem is, when I press `Esc`, and then hit `:` to do `:wq`, it starts recording a macro.

But then it doesn't even seem like Vim.  As a sanity test, if I enter the "Vim window" (the one that I go into after running `git merge master`), and I press `Esc` `j`, it goes into some `[justified file]` mode, and goes all the way to the bottom of the text (instead of like normal, going down one line).

Why is it doing this?  What is this?

Comment: What does the command `git config core.editor` print?

Comment: Nothing, it seems

Comment: if `core.editor` is not set, git falls back to environment variables `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`. Do you have either of them set to something other than `vim`?

Comment: Sorry, how do I check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
git var GIT_EDITOR
```

to know which editor git is using. Once you know which editor you use, you’ll be able to look for specific help for this editor. You can set the editor used by git with `git config --global core.editor vim` (for instance).

Git chooses the editor to use based on ([in this order](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var)) and the previous command `git var GIT_EDITOR` goes through this:

1. The environment variable `$GIT_EDITOR`
2. Value of `core.editor` in the configuration file (check with `git config core.editor`)
3. The environment variable `$VISUAL`
4. The environment variable `$EDITOR`

*Note*: In general, the value of an environment variable `$VAR` can be checked with `echo $VAR` in your shell.